# Separate string without comma in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, function

My original string is

```
one,two,three,four,five,
```

I need separate each word as a link

```
<a href="">one</a>, <a href="">two</a>, <a href="">three</a>, ...
```

My code is

```
$plat = $row['reg'];
foreach ($plat as $key => $pv) {
    $pl[] = implode(',', $pv);
}
for ($p = 1; $p = sizeof($pl); $i++) {
    echo '<a href="#" rel="tag">' . $pl[i] . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: as simple use `explode(",",$str)` to split string with comma in array and use it as you want

Comment: @SatishSharma not only, he need to put second interator into first like in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would suffice..

```
<?php
$str='one,two,three,four,five';
$arr=explode(',',$str);
foreach($arr as $val)
{
echo "<a href=''>$val</a>, ";
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
<a href=''>one</a>, <a href=''>two</a>, <a href=''>three</a>, <a href=''>four</a>, <a href=''>five</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   <?php
     $str='one two three four five';
      $arr=explode(' ',$str);
      foreach($arr as $val)
        {
         echo "<a href=''>$val</a>, ";
         }
        this Code to separate blank spacesepration
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'one,two,three,four,five';
$tag_open = '<a href="#" rel="tag">';
$tag_close = '</a>';
echo $tag_open. implode($tag_close.', '.$tag_open, explode(',', $string)). $tag_close;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
$plat=$row['reg'];
foreach ($plat as $key=> $pv) {
    $pl[] = explode(',', $pv);
    for($p=1;$p=sizeof($pl); $i++) {
        echo '<a href="#" rel="tag">'.trim($pl[i]).'</a>';
    }
}
```